# Does liquibase support kerberos authentication with mongodb connection?

Tags: mongodb, kerberos, liquibase

Can only find examples for oracle db using kerberos. Is there any way I can use kerberos authentication while using liquibase with mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, I would say yes since it's supported for Oracle and MSSQL.

- https://docs.liquibase.com/install/tutorials/mssql-integrated-security-kerberos-authentication.html
- https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/setting-up-java-applications-to-communicate-with

That second link, especially, should help you, just use Liquibase as the Java application and follow these steps from MongoDB.